# Cakephp beforeSave() implementation situation

Tags: mysql, cakephp, before-save

I am making a CakePHP website which allows Users to fill out a Signup Form.  I have a Users table and one of the fields to fill in is ZipCode.  What I really need to know is their Latitude/Longitude.  So, I have another table called Locations which lists all the ZipCodes in the USA along with the Lat/Long for that ZipCode.

So what I need to do, is upon a User hitting the Submit Button, take the ZipCode that they entered, query the Locations table and return the Latitude and Longitude and store the Latitude and Longitude in the Users table.  Obviously, I will check to see if a valid Lat/Long was returned before the actual save to the Users table.

I know a little about CakePHP and I believe I have to use a beforeSave() Function.
Can anyone guide me further into how to do all this?

So, to be a little more clear....I have a Users Table with fields...name, address, city, zipcode, latitude, longitude...etc.

Since hardly anyone knows their Lat/Long....I am taking their ZipCode and querying a Locations Table that will return a Lat/Long of their Zipcode.  Then storing all their Form information plus the Lat/Long I get from the Locations Table into the Users Table.  And if they give me a bogus ZipCode, I will throw an error and ask them for the right zipcode.

How do I do this in CakePHP?

Comment: Of course you can do it and it's quite easy. But why don't you just join the two tables using the zip code as foreign key so that every time you query a user you also get the location information?

Comment: You can use [this behavior](http://www.dereuromark.de/2012/06/12/geocoding-with-cakephp/) and some validation on top to only allow valid zipcodes (incl. valid lat/lng) to be saved.

Comment: Arila....can you show me how to do what I asked?  Your suggestion of joining the tables is not what I want.  I want to validate their zipcode BEFORE I save their user info in the Users table.  That way if they give me a bogus zipcode, I can immediately catch that and force them to give me a valid zipcode.